# Rails redirection to edit path wrong with value from application controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Rails app with this route:

```
edit_admin_review GET    /admin/reviews/:id/edit(.:format)                                  admin/reviews#edit
```

I have user form in Review Show with this html & controller:

```
<%= form_for @user, url: admin_user_path(@user.id), html: {method: :put}, remote: true do |f| %> 
  <div class="row">
      <%= f.label "Name" %>
      <%= f.text_field "name" %>
  </div>
  .....
<% end %>
```

Admin User Controller update method:

```
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    params[:user][:gender] = params[:user][:gender].to_i
    @user.update(user_edit_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "User details saved"
      redirect_to edit_admin_review_path(@user.reviews.last.id)
    else
      flash[:alert] = "ERROR: #{@user.errors.messages.first.second.first}"
      redirect_to edit_admin_review_path(@user.reviews.last.id)
    end
  end
```

In Application Controller I have this:

```
  before_action :location

  protected
  def location
    country = cookies[:country] ||= request.location.country
    if country.present?
      country = ISO3166::Country[country]
      @location = country.translations[I18n.locale.to_s] || country.name
    else
      @location = "Malaysia"
    end
  end
```

For some reason, the `edit_admin_review_path(@user.reviews.last.id)` is redirecting to this path: `url.com/admin/reviews/73/Malaysia` ... for some reason instead of :id/edit, it will take the location variable from Application Controller and add it to the link.

When I removed the location method, it works well and redirect as expected. I know I can probably solve it by skipping this for the action but what I don't understand is why it gets the value from location if it has nothing to do with the form itself?

What is the best way to go around and why it's happening?

Comment: show the update action code please

Comment: @ArupRakshit just updated it but I think the major issue is the redirection when it goes wrong

Comment: It's probably an issue with how you have configured your `routes.rb`. Can you update your question with it?

Comment: @Dudis I was playing in a test application.. couldn't reproduce it.. seems your application specific bug

Comment: What is your rails version?

Comment: I'm not sure, but could it be that @location is used by rails internally? can you try using another name for the variable? By the way, you could move the redirect after the if/else since it's the same in both cases

Comment: @arieljuod I thought that too, and tried in a new Rails 5.2 app.. but it is working.. Generally we do have `request.location`, not anything `location` publicly..

Comment: Renaming @location solved the problem, thanks for a good tip! Please feel free to add it as official answer so I can mark it